# Filter eager-loaded has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Suppose I have the following two classes:

```
class Group
  has_many :actions
end

class Action
  belongs_to :group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And I want to retrieve all Groups with their Actions, i.e. :

```
Group.includes(:actions)
```

But I want to filter the loaded actions by the current user's user_id, so when iterating the 'actions' association, only the user's Actions would be returned.

I could add another association, like so:

```
has_many :current_user_actions, -> {where(user_id: User.current_user.id)}, class_name: 'Action'
```

But the aforementioned Group query feeds a view that iterates over the 'actions' (and not 'current_user_actions') association, so that option's ruled out.

The following query, suggested below, would work except that the where clause filters out Groups without Actions:

```
Group.includes(:actions).where('actions.user_id = ?', User.current_user.id).references(:actions)
```

Comment: why are you using  User.current_user.id if you can simply write it current_user.id

Comment: current_user is a controller action, but my code's in the model. User.current_user is my own method.

Comment: and you cant change the view?

Comment: I'd rather the view remain ignorant to whether the Group it's displaying is filtered or not.

Comment: Did you try `Group.includes(:actions).where('actions.user_id = ?', User.current_user.id).references(:actions)`?

Comment: That works except the where clause filters out Groups without Actions (I'll edit the post to specify that requirement). Tried to run it with a "LEFT OUTER JOIN ON..." but that doesn't filter the association.